# how to update the value of the variable in laravel controller every time the function is called

Tags: laravel, function

```php
public function index()
{
    $a = 1;
    $b = 2;
    $c = 3;

    $x = array($a,$b,$c);

    if($x == range(1,3)) {
        print_r("hello");
    }

    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $x[$i] += $x[2];
    }

    $a = $x[0];
    $b = $x[1];
    $c = $x[2];
}
```

I want every time the function is called $x[] should be update with new values ( like $a = $x[0];)

Comment: So, everytime you want new `$a,$b & $c`? Am I right?

Comment: yes.like first time it is 1,2,3 and next time updated as 4,5,6 and then next time 7,8,9 and so on

Comment: Put it in your session

Comment: Either you can put in your session or you can use global variables.

Comment: I tried that but Its not working.could you please explain more

Comment: tried both the options

Comment: private $a = 1;
private $b = 2;
private $c = 3;


  public function index(){

    $a = $this->a;
    $b = $this->b;
    $c = $this->c;

Comment: @anonymous Try this:
if ($request->session()->has('lastValue')) {
   $value = $request->session()->get('lastValue');
   $a = $value + 1; 
   $b = $value + 2; 
   $c = $value + 3;
  $request->session()->put('lastValue', $c);
} else {
  $a = 1;
  $b = 2;
  $c = 3;
  $request->session()->put('lastValue', $c);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this.

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $a = $request->session()->get('a') ?: 1;
    $b = $request->session()->get('b') ?: 2;
    $c = $request->session()->get('c') ?: 3;

    $x = array($a,$b,$c);

    if($x == range(1,3)) {
        print_r("hello");
    }

    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $x[$i] += $x[2];
    }

    $a = $x[0];
    $b = $x[1];
    $c = $x[2];

    $request->session()->put('a', $a);
    $request->session()->put('b', $b);
    $request->session()->put('c', $c);
}
```